# emit in fuction in vue 3 composition api

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, emit

I have a timer, and a function by which the timer stops. I want to use emit in a function, it doesn't work.

```
 const stopTimer = () => {
  clearInterval(timer.value);

  const emit = defineEmits(["end"]);
  emit("end", reactionTime.value);
};
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Also, you usually define `defineEmits` at the top of your `script` tag, not in the function itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defineEmits` should be called top-level in `<script setup>` and not inside any arrow function.